# mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys error

Tags: cocoa, swift

So i was trying to get some information about my usb devices and all of them seem to have the same output for NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey, and NSURLVolumeIsReadOnlyKey. I do see the different key names and correct volume sizes, is there an issue with my code? or is this something else?

```
var filemanager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
    var keys: NSArray = [NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey,NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey,NSURLVolumeIsReadOnlyKey,NSURLVolumeMaximumFileSizeKey]
    var url = filemanager.mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys(keys, options: nil)!
    for items in url
    {
        var a: AnyObject?
        var b: AnyObject?
        var c: AnyObject?
        var d: AnyObject?
        var e: AnyObject?

        var err: NSError?
        items.getPromisedItemResourceValue(&a, forKey: NSURLVolumeNameKey, error: &err)
        items.getPromisedItemResourceValue(&b, forKey: NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, error: &err)
        items.getPromisedItemResourceValue(&c, forKey: NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey, error: &err)
        items.getPromisedItemResourceValue(&d, forKey: NSURLVolumeIsReadOnlyKey, error: &err)
        items.getPromisedItemResourceValue(&e, forKey: NSURLVolumeMaximumFileSizeKey, error: &err)


        println("itemname: \(items)")
        println(a!)
        println(b!)
        println(c!)
        println(d!)
        println(e)

    }
```

Comment: You don't explain why you expect the values for those keys to differ between the volumes. What are the values, what did you expect them to be, and why? There's no good reason to use `-getPromisedItemResourceValue:forKey:error:` instead of `-getResourceValue:forKey:error:`, but I doubt it causes a problem. You should, however, be checking the return value before using the output value.

Comment: When I run this, it show the correct drive path, name and size but returns zeroes for everything else. I have a usb drive connected and I am expecting to get anything other than a zero for the mountable and removable key for it